# Convert list of dataframes with different col- and row numbers into an 3 dimensional array in R

Tags: r, arrays, list, 3d

```
df1<-data.frame(ID=1:3,test=2:4,category=1)   
df2<-data.frame(ID=1:2,test=4:5,test1=2:3,category=2)
Mylist<-list(df1,df2)
```

I tried

```
array1<-array(unlist(Mylist))
```

expected result is that array1 looks like this

```
array1[ , ,1]
      [,1]      [,2]        [,3]     
[1,] 1           2           1 
[2,] 2           3           1 
[3,] 3           4           1 

array1[ , ,2]
      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     
[1,]   1          4         2         2
[2,]   2          5         3         2
```

But I do not know how to specify the dimension of the array since each matrix/dataframe has different col/row numbers.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: We can help you with how to specify the dimensions of the array if you tell us what you want the dimensions of the array to be. Do you want pad out the shorter dimensions with 0s or `NA`s? Do you truncate the longer matrices down to match size with the smaller ones?  Do you want to "recycle" the matrix rows/columns to a lowest common multiple of size? Or something else?

Comment: I edited my question. Maybe now you can understand what I am aiming for. If it is not possible to get my target solution, I think producing NA s would be an option, if there is a way to ignore NA s in further calculations.

Comment: Just like data frames need the same number of rows in each column, arrays have the same dimensions in each slice. What you're showing looks like a `list`. What about lists aren't working for you that you need an array? This feels a lot [like an XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

One strategy could be using `abind`.

1. We determine the max number of rows and columns in the list
2. Pad each matrix/df with NA
3. Finally, convert the list to 3-dimensional array with `abind`

```
# given list
A1 <- matrix(runif(500), 25, 20)
A2 <- matrix(runif(483), 23, 21)
A3 <- matrix(runif(600), 24, 25)
MyList <- list(A1, A2, A3)

# 1. get max rows and cols:
max_rows <- max(sapply(MyList, nrow))
max_cols <- max(sapply(MyList, ncol))

# 2. pad with NA
MyList <- lapply(MyList, function(x) {
  rows_missing <- max_rows - nrow(x)
  cols_missing <- max_cols - ncol(x)
  padded <- matrix(NA, nrow = max_rows, ncol = max_cols)
  padded[1:nrow(x), 1:ncol(x)] <- x
  padded
})

# 3. get 3-dimensional array
array1 <- abind(MyList, along = 3)
```

Comment: This is not working when I use this for a list of dataframes. Therefore I edited the question  such that my list containts dataframes

Comment: Convert all your data frames to matrices first. Just like a matrix, an array must have all one class, just like a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can't be ragged.  If `a` is the resulting array then `a[,,1]` and `a[,,2]` must have the same dimensions.

**1)** With that caveat create the input list `L` and from that compute the set of `IDs`.  Merge each component of `L` with `IDs` and row bind the results into a single wide form data frame.  Convert that to long form using `pivot_longer` and then to an array using `tapply`.  This puts the dnn variables into the dimnames rather than the data.  See (2) if you prefer to have them in the data instead.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# inputs
dnn <- c("ID", "test", "category") # desired order of dimensions
L <- list(df1, df2)  # main input

# same as merge except it defaults to all = TRUE
Merge <- function(..., all = TRUE) merge(..., all = all)

IDs <- L %>%
  lapply(function(x) x["ID"]) %>%
  Reduce(Merge, .) 

a <- L %>%
  lapply(Merge, IDs) %>%
  bind_rows %>%
  pivot_longer(!all_of(setdiff(dnn, "test")), names_to = "test") %>%
  with(tapply(value, .[dnn], c))
a
```

giving

```
, , category = 1

   test
ID  test test1
  1    2    NA
  2    3    NA
  3    4    NA

, , category = 2

   test
ID  test test1
  1    4     2
  2    5     3
  3   NA    NA
```

**2)** Another possibility is the following.  The output is closer to that in the question; however, (1) may be preferred depending on what  you want.  We compute `IDs` and then a wide form data frame, `DF`, as in (1) and then use `abind with that.

```
library(abind)
library(dplyr)

Merge <- function(..., all = TRUE) merge(..., all = all)

L <- list(df1, df2)
IDs <- Reduce(Merge, lapply(L, function(x) x["ID"]))
DF <- bind_rows(lapply(L, Merge, IDs))
nid <- nrow(IDs)
a <- abind(split(DF, rep(1:(nrow(DF) / nid), each = nid)), along = 3)
a
```

giving:

```
, , 1

     ID test category test1
[1,]  1    2        1    NA
[2,]  2    3        1    NA
[3,]  3    4        1    NA

, , 2

     ID test category test1
[1,]  1    4        2     2
[2,]  2    5        2     3
[3,]  3   NA       NA    NA
```

### Note

The inputs, as shown in the question, are

```
df1<-data.frame(ID=1:3,test=2:4,category=1)
df2<-data.frame(ID=1:2,test=4:5,test1=2:3,category=2)
```

### Update

Added (1).